# Me podrian decir la diferencia entre Archivos directos y secuenciales en C++

Tags: c++

¿Cuál es la diferencia entre archivos directos y secuenciales? Si pueden brindarme un ejemplo de cada uno con las sintaxis que llevan en C++ por favor.

Comment: Bienvenido al sitio @shadowkira_123. Por favor muestra lo que tú has revisado por tu cuenta para aprender al respecto o qué es lo que te dificulta para comprender estos conceptos.

Answer (score 2):

No se a qué te refieres con "archivos directos"; pero respecto a archivos secuenciales no es un tipo de archivo si no un modo de acceso a archivos.

> En ciencias de la computación, el acceso secuencial significa que un grupo de elementos es accedido en un predeterminado orden secuencial (un registro a la vez).
>
> Secuencialmente, a veces, es la única forma de acceder a los datos, por ejemplo, en una cinta magnética.
>
> También puede ser el método de acceso elegido, para simplemente procesar una secuencia de datos en orden.

Fuente: [Wikipedia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acceso_secuencial).

[image: Fuente: [Wikipedia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acceso_secuencial)]

---

Para poder leer archivos en C++ ya sea de manera secuencial o aleatoria, opino que la mejor opción es usar [streams de archivos](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_fstream) ([`FILE`](http://es.cppreference.com/w/c/io) es de [c](/questions/tagged/c), aunque también usable en [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b)).

Los stream de archivo de C++ disponen de varias funciones que permiten leer datos del archivo. La mayoría de estas funciones mueven adelante automáticamente el puntero de lectura de datos, así que con estas funciones la lectura sería secuencial, estas funciones serían:

- [Lectura con formato (`>>`)](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt).
- [Lectura de una línea](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/getline).
- Lectura sin formato: [X bytes](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/read) o [hasta X bytes](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/readsome).
- [Lee e ignora](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/ignore).

Se puede manipular la posición del puntero de lectura antes o después de realizar una lectura, si entre lecturas mueves dicho puntero la lectura será aleatoria en lugar de secuencial; las funciones que manipulan este puntero son:

- [Deshace la última lectura](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/unget).
- [Posiciona el puntero de lectura](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/seekg).

Puedes saber la posición actual del puntero de lectura con [tellg](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/tellg).

---

Añado un sencillo ejemplo de uso, de lectura de archivos, está usando la librería [`<fstream>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/fstream):

```
// Crea un stream de archivo de lectura.
// "i" corresponde a lectura (input)
// "f" corresponde a archivo (file)
// si el stream fuese "o" lo abriria como escritura (ofstream)
std::ifstream archivo{"archivo.txt"};

// Comprueba si esta abierto, de ser asi: sigue.
if (archivo.is_open())
{
    int valor{};
    std::string texto{};

    // Lee secuencialmente un int y un string
    archivo >> valor;
    archivo >> texto;

    // Rebobina a la posicion donde se acaba el dato "valor"
    archivo.seekg(sizeof(valor));
    char letra{};
    // Lee un caracter.
    arthivo.read(&letra, 1);
}
```