# ¿Como cargar un archivo de texto a una Lista Enlazada en C++?

Tags: c++, ordenamiento

Que tal mi problema es tal cual lo menciona el titulo, tengo conocimientos de cómo realizar listas simples y dobles enlazadas en c++, pero no tengo idea de cómo pasar información de un fichero de texto a una lista simple. Tengo un programa creado en c++ con índices en archivos y mi programa hace todo esto:

- Agregar
- Mostrar
- Buscar
- Eliminar
- Modificar
- Mostrar indices

Pero la única opción que me falta es **Mostrar ordenadamente**. Para esto me piden utilizar un TDA y tengo que tomar los datos desde el archivo de texto y agregarlos al TDA para después ordenarlos y mostrarlos. Mi proyecto maneja 2 archivos de texto ya que es por índices, unos es **Datos.txt**(guarda toda la información) y otro es **Indice.txt**(guarda los índices).

Los datos que se piden al agregar son los siguientes:

```
cout << "Codigo: ";
cin.getline(Dis.codigo,10);
cout << "Nombre: ";
cin.getline(Dis.nombre,30);
cout << "Cantante: ";
cin.getline(Dis.cantante,30);
cout << "Genero: ";
cin.getline(Dis.genero,20);
cout << "Precio: ";
fflush(stdin);
cin.getline(Dis.precio,10);
cout << "Discografia: ";
cin.getline(Dis.discografia,20);
cout << "Disco agregado correctamente" << endl;
system("pause");
ofstream a("datos.txt",ios::app);
ofstream b("indice.txt",ios::app);
a.write((char*)&Dis,sizeof(Dis));
a.seekp(0,ios::end);
Ind.pos=a.tellp()/sizeof(Dis);
strcpy(Ind.codigo,codigo);
b.write((char*)&Ind,sizeof(Ind));
b.close();
a.close();
```

Estos datos se guardan el archivo **Datos.txt** y el código se guarda en **Indice.txt** junto con una posición. Espero me de a entender con el planteamiento de mi problema que es solo el como poder agregar los datos que están en el .txt a una lista simple enlazada y mostrarla ordenadamente.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hago un intento por comprender la situación.

**Misión**: *Volcar dos archivos de texto en una lista de discos*.

#### ➢ Creación de un TDA o TAD (tipo abstracto de datos)

Lo primero es crear la estructura `Dis` (disco), de esta forma.

```
struct Dis
{
    string codigo;
    string nombre;
    string cantante;
    string genero;
    string discografia;
    string precio;

    Dis* siguiente; //Puntero al siguiente disco (importante).
};
struct Ind
{
    int pos;
    string codigo;
};
```

**Nota:** Este tipo de estructuras no pueden venir en un archivo de texto, ya que un `string` es un puntero a una cadena de caracteres, que tienen tamaño dinámico. Es decir, todos los enteros ocupan 32 o 64 bits dependiendo de la arquitectura, siempre es el mismo número, pero una cadena, `"Pedro"`, no ocupa lo mismo que `"Juan"`, la primera 4 y la segunda 5, y a pesar de eso, los dos son de tipo string, entonces no se le puede hacer `sizeof`.

#### ➢ Manejar un archivo

Para el manejo de archivos, es necesario la biblioteca estándard `stdio`, el `main` debe quedar de la siguiente manera. El `stdlib` alguna que otra vez hace falta, así que lo dejamos, sin prestarle atención para qué sirve.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main (int argc, char** argv)
{
    //Cosas por hacer.
    return 0;
}
```

Para esto es necesario saber cómo se manejan los archivos en **C**, aunque también funciona en **C++** ya que es un lenguaje acumulativo. Así que encontré el siguiente enlace que trata ese tema:

[Programación en C - Manejo de archivos - WikiLibros](https://es.wikibooks.org/wiki/Programaci%C3%B3n_en_C/Manejo_de_archivos).

1. Crear un *apuntador* del tipo `FILE`.
2. Abrir el archivo utilizando la función **fopen** y asignándole el resultado de la llamada a nuestro apuntador.
3. Hacer las diversas operaciones (**lectura**, **escritura**, etc).
4. Cerrar el archivo utilizando la función **fclose**.

Pseudo-código:

```
Abrir archivo.
Leerlo.
Volcarlo en lista_enlazada //Nodo.
Cerrarlo.
```

#### ➢ Abrir un archivo

Una lista de parámetros **opentype** para la función **fopen** son:

> `"r"` : Lectura, el fichero debe existir.
>
> `"w"` : Escritura, se crea si no existe o se sobreescribe si existe.
>
> `"a"` : Escritura al final del contenido, si no existe se crea.
>
> `"r+"` : Lectura y escritura, el fichero debe existir.
>
> `"w+"` : Lectura y escritura, se crea si no existe o se sobreescribe si existe.
>
> `"r+b"` ó `"rb+"` : Modo binario para actualización (lectura y escritura).
>
> `"rb"` : Modo binario para lectura.

En nuestro caso vamos a usar *Lectura no Binaria*, es decir, `"r"`, ya que estamos manejando archivos `txt` (texto plano) y no imágenes o audio.

Código: Estos son los pasos 1 y 2 en una misma línea.

```
FILE* archivo = fopen("Datos.txt","r"); //Para Indice.txt es lo mismo.
```

#### ➢ Leer un archivo

> 1) Lee de a un caracter.
>
> `char fgetc(FILE *archivo)`
>
> 2) Lee de a una línea o el tamaño indicado.
>
> `char *fgets(char *buffer, int tamano, FILE *archivo)`
>
> 3) Lee de a bloques.
>
> `size_t fread(void *puntero, size_t tamano, size_t cantidad, FILE
>   *archivo);`
>
> 4) Funciona igual que la entrada por teclado pero desde un archivo.
>
> `int fscanf(FILE *fichero, const char *formato, argumento, ...);`

En nuestro caso nos interesa `fgetc`, ya que la estructura `Dis` no puede venir en un archivo.

Código: Esto hace que lea de a un caracter.

```
while(feof(archivo) == 0)
{
    char caracter = fgetc(archivo);
    //Hacer algo con el caracter.
}
```

#### ➢ Cerrar un archivo

Código:

```
fclose(archivo);
```

---

Ya vimos las operaciones básicas acerca de las operaciones con archivos. Ahora nos queda pensar en cómo volcarlo a la estructura de datos `Dis`.

Como no mostraste un *archivo de texto de ejemplo* para saber cómo pueden venir los **datos** del disco, voy a suponer que tiene el siguiente **formato**. Es más, creo que de esta manera no hace falta leer el *archivo de índice*, así que no voy a tocar ese tema.

> codigo_1 nombre_1 cantante_1 genero_1 discografia_1 precio_1
>
> codigo_2 nombre_2 cantante_2 genero_2 discografia_2 precio_2
>
> Etcétera...

Para eso hay que tener en cuenta dos excepciones, cualquier caracter excepto los espacios, (es decir, `' '`, `'\x20'` ), o un salto de línea, ( `'\n`, `\r`, `\x0D`, `\x0A` ). El espacio significa el siguiente campo de la estructura, el salto de línea, el siguiente disco.

#### ➢ ¿Cómo leer un archivo con este nuevo formato?

Código: Retomamos el código anterior sobre leer el caracter y le agregamos cosas.

```
Dis discos = new Dis()
string texto="";
int i=0; //Número de campo actual.
string campos[6]; //Array de campos de texto que luego pasarán a los discos.
while(feof(archivo) == 0)
{
    char caracter = fgetc(archivo);
    if( caracter!=' ' && ! esSaltoLinea(caracter) )
    {
        texto = texto+((string)(caracter)); //Agrega un caracter al final del texto
    }
    else
    {
        campos[i] = texto;
        texto = "";
        if( caracter==' ' ){i++;} //Suma 1 a la variable i.

        if( esSaltoLinea(caracter) )
        {
            //Volcar los textos de la variable campos al disco actual mediante un for.
            //Cambiar al disco siguiente.

            i=0; //Vuelve al campo inicial.
        }
    }
}
```

**Nota:** Dejo algunas cosas sin hacer para que practiques tranquilo, no son tan difíciles tampoco.

#### ➢ Ordenamiento de una estructura

En el siguiente ejemplo voy a ordenar los discos por código. Hay que aclarar que el método más eficiente de ordenamiento es el que permite la búsqueda binaria, este es eficaz solamente y es lento en comparación con el otro.

```
void ordenarPorCodigo( Dis discos )
{
    Dis* principal = discos;
    Dis* actual = principal;
    Dis* auxiliar;

    while( actual->siguiente!=NULL )
    {
        siguiente = actual->siguiente;

        if(  strcmp(actual->codigo,actual->siguiente->codigo) > 0 )
        {
            //Copiar los datos del actual en auxiliar.
            //Copiar los datos del siguiente en actual.
            //Copiar los datos del auxiliar en el siguiente.

            //Ajustar los punteros del actual y del siguiente de manera correcta.

            actual = principal;
        }
        actual = actual->siguiente;
    }
}
```

**Nota:** Nuevamente, te dejo como desafío esos pequeños detalles.

Comment: ¿Por qué `FILE` (de librerías C) en lugar de `std::fstream` (de librerías C++)? De hecho [Eduardo Javier Maldonado](http://es.stackoverflow.com/q/24131/2742) está usando `ofstream` en su código.

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster Por nada en especial, directamente lo otro no lo sé usar.

Comment: Es una pena porque la respuesta es excelente, pero no tan buena como podría ser... insisto: `FILE` es un sistema de manejo de archivos de C, no de C++.

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster Voy a investigar eso entonces, para la próxima que vea una pregunta de estas.

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster Ya encontré un [enlace](http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/9697/me-podrian-decir-la-diferencia-entre-archivos-directos-y-secuenciales-en-c) que habla sobre eso, y curiosamente es una respuesta tuya. ¿Si leo eso lo podré aprender?

Comment: la capacidad de aprender es tanto del que enseña como del que aprende y mientras que no dudo de tu capacidad de aprender sí que dudo de que puedas aprender sólo con hilos de SOes (más aún si son míos). Mi consejo es que hagas tus propios experimentos con `std::fstream` para coger práctica :)

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45591/discussion-between-arteze-and-paperbirdmaster).

Comment: Tengo bastantes ejemplos de como trabajo archivos de texto con fstream por si los quisieras mirar te comparto los códigos. Manejo delimitadores, campos de dimensión, indices y estoy terminando indices invertidos.

Comment: @EduardoJavierMaldonado Puedes ver mi perfil (que lo acabo de editar) y enviarme alguno de esos ejemplos por correo, preferiría el servicio Mediafire.

Comment: @ArtEze ya te envie el de indización por medio de tu correo electrónico.